# Saving a referenced object (via Ref) in one call using Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I'm using objectify and Google Cloud Endpoints to develop app's back-end. I have a "Truck" class which have a reference (using Ref) to the "Category" class. It looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class Truck {

   public @Id Long id;
   public String city;
   //...
   @Load Ref<PlaceCategory> category;

   public PlaceCategory getCategory(){
       return category.get();
   }

   public void setCategory(PlaceCategory category){
       this.category = Ref.create(category);
   }
}
```

Naturally, Category class is just another Entity with it's own id.

Now, building the API I'd like to be able - in one call - insert a Truck object which contains a Category object. The request body in this case will looks like this:

```
{
 "category": {
  "name": "Some category"
 },
 "city": "Some city"
}
```

(It's just a copy from API explorer).
However executing this request I receive an error:

> com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   No class 'entities.Category' was registered (through reference chain: entities.Truck[\"category\"])

Of course I've registered Category object in OfyService:

```
public class OfyService {

    static {
        factory().register(PlaceCategory.class);
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

I've read the docs twice and still I have no idea where's the problem. There's no explicitly said that I can't embed object like this. After 2 days of searching and trying I'm giving up :) Hope someone can help me understand.

Comment: Ever found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The following code, very close to yours, works well for me both on the development server and on App Engine.

I'm using App Engine 1.8.9 and Objectify 4.0b3, maybe you're using an older version and just need to upgrade ?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hatanian.david.cloudplatform</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-objectify-ref</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Simple Endpoints API</name>

    <properties>
        <appengine.target.version>1.8.9</appengine.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>4.0b3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints</directory>
                            <!-- the list has a default value of ** -->
                            <includes>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.discovery</include>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.api</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Ofyservice :

```
package hatanian.david.simpleendpoint;

import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

public class OfyService {

    static {
        factory().register(PlaceCategory.class);
        factory().register(Truck.class);
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

PlaceCategory :

```
@Entity
public class PlaceCategory {
    @Id
    private String category;

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Truck :

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class Truck {

   public @Id Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Load
   Ref<PlaceCategory> category;

   public PlaceCategory getCategory(){
       return category.get();
   }

   public void setCategory(PlaceCategory category){
       this.category = Ref.create(category);
   }
}
```

And the Endpoint :

```
@Api(name = "simple", version = "v1", scopes = {EndPointsConstants.EMAIL_SCOPE}, clientIds = {EndPointsConstants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID})
public class SimpleEndpoint {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SimpleEndpoint.class.getName());

    @ApiMethod(name = "create", httpMethod = "post")
    public void create() {
        PlaceCategory placeCategory = new PlaceCategory();
        placeCategory.setCategory("testcategory");
        OfyService.ofy().save().entity(placeCategory).now();

        Truck truck = new Truck();
        truck.setCategory(placeCategory);
        truck.setId(1L);
        OfyService.ofy().save().entity(truck).now();
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "gettruck", httpMethod = "get")
    public Truck getTruck() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy().load().key(Key.create(Truck.class, 1L)).now();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've missed to register the Truck-class. This:

```
static 
{
   factory().register(PlaceCategory.class);
}
```

Should be (as seen in Davids loooong example):

```
static 
{
   factory().register(PlaceCategory.class);
   factory().register(Truck.class);
}
```